# threejs: How to achieve a cleaner animation code?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, requestanimationframe

I am currently making a threejs animation. It was a little bit complicated, since I had to change the pivots of the objects everytime another animation is going to happen and rearange every object to it's right position (probably some of you will know this issue, who has some animation experience).

I achieved finally the right animation, but the code is a little clunky. I put everything in the `animation()` function and in result I have something like this:

***JavaScript:***

```
function animate() {

        //Animation 1
        if (frontPivot1.rotation.x<=Math.PI && backPivot1.rotation.x>=-Math.PI) {
            frontPivot1.add(mesh1);
            frontPivot1.add(mesh2);
            backPivot1.add(mesh5);
            backPivot1.add(mesh6);
            mesh1.position.z = -5;
            mesh2.position.z = -5;
            mesh5.position.z = 5;
            mesh6.position.z = 5;
            frontPivot1.rotation.x += Math.PI / 90;
            backPivot1.rotation.x += -Math.PI / 90;
        }

        //Animation 2
        if((frontPivot1.rotation.x>=Math.PI && backPivot1.rotation.x<=-Math.PI) && (centerPivotCCW2.rotation.z <= 0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCW2.rotation.z >= -0.5*Math.PI)) {

            //CCW
            centerPivotCCW2.add(mesh1);
            centerPivotCCW2.add(mesh4);
            centerPivotCCW2.add(mesh6);
            centerPivotCCW2.add(mesh7);

            mesh1.position.z = 15;
            mesh1.rotation.x = Math.PI;

            mesh4.position.y=5;

            mesh6.position.z = -15;
            mesh6.rotation.x = Math.PI;

            mesh7.position.y=5;

            //CW
            centerPivotCW2.add(mesh2);
            centerPivotCW2.add(mesh3);
            centerPivotCW2.add(mesh5);
            centerPivotCW2.add(mesh8);

            mesh2.position.z = 15;
            mesh2.rotation.x = Math.PI;

            mesh3.position.y=5;

            mesh5.position.z = -15;
            mesh5.rotation.x = Math.PI;

            mesh8.position.y=5;

            centerPivotCCW2.rotation.z += Math.PI / 90;
            centerPivotCW2.rotation.z += -Math.PI / 90;

            camera.position.y += -0.224;
        }

        //Animation 3
        if(centerPivotCCW2.rotation.z >= 0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCW2.rotation.z <= -0.5*Math.PI && (centerPivotCCW3.rotation.x >= -0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCW3.rotation.x <= 0.5*Math.PI)){
            //CW
            centerPivotCW3.add(mesh1);
            centerPivotCW3.add(mesh2);
            centerPivotCW3.add(mesh3);
            centerPivotCW3.add(mesh4);

            mesh1.rotation.z=-0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh2.rotation.z=0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh3.rotation.z=-0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh4.rotation.z=0.5*Math.PI;

            //CCW
            centerPivotCCW3.add(mesh5);
            centerPivotCCW3.add(mesh6);
            centerPivotCCW3.add(mesh7);
            centerPivotCCW3.add(mesh8);

            mesh5.rotation.z=-0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh6.rotation.z=0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh7.rotation.z=-0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh8.rotation.z=0.5*Math.PI;

            centerPivotCW3.rotation.x += Math.PI / 90;
            centerPivotCCW3.rotation.x += -Math.PI / 90;

            camera.position.y += -0.448;
        }

        //Animation 4
        if(centerPivotCCW3.rotation.x <= -0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCW3.rotation.x >= 0.5*Math.PI && (leftPivot4.rotation.z <= Math.PI && rightPivot4.rotation.z >= -Math.PI)){
            //Left
            leftPivot4.add(mesh4);
            leftPivot4.add(mesh7);

            mesh4.position.x=5;
            mesh7.position.x=5;

            mesh4.rotation.x=0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh7.rotation.x=1.5*Math.PI;

            //Rightt
            rightPivot4.add(mesh3);
            rightPivot4.add(mesh8);

            mesh3.position.x=-5;
            mesh8.position.x=-5;

            mesh3.rotation.x=0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh8.rotation.x=1.5*Math.PI;

            leftPivot4.rotation.z+= Math.PI / 90;
            rightPivot4.rotation.z+= -Math.PI / 90;

        }

        //Animation 5
        if(leftPivot4.rotation.z >= Math.PI && rightPivot4.rotation.z <= -Math.PI && (centerPivotCW5.rotation.x <= 0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCCW5.rotation.x >= -0.5*Math.PI)){
            //CW
            centerPivotCW5.add(mesh1);
            centerPivotCW5.add(mesh2);
            centerPivotCW5.add(mesh3);
            centerPivotCW5.add(mesh4);

            mesh1.position.z=5;
            mesh2.position.z=5;
            mesh3.position.x=15;
            mesh4.position.x=-15;

            mesh1.rotation.x=1.5*Math.PI;
            mesh2.rotation.x=1.5*Math.PI;
            mesh3.rotation.y=Math.PI;
            mesh4.rotation.y=Math.PI;

            //CCW
            centerPivotCCW5.add(mesh5);
            centerPivotCCW5.add(mesh6);
            centerPivotCCW5.add(mesh7);
            centerPivotCCW5.add(mesh8);

            mesh5.position.z=-5;
            mesh6.position.z=-5;
            mesh7.position.x=-15;
            mesh8.position.x=15;

            mesh5.rotation.x=0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh6.rotation.x=0.5*Math.PI;
            mesh7.rotation.y=2*Math.PI;
            mesh8.rotation.y=2*Math.PI;


            centerPivotCW5.rotation.x += Math.PI / 90;
            centerPivotCCW5.rotation.x += -Math.PI / 90;

            camera.position.y += -0.224;
        }

        //Animation 6

        if(centerPivotCW5.rotation.x >= 0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCCW5.rotation.x <= -0.5*Math.PI && (centerPivotCW6.rotation.z <= 0.5*Math.PI && centerPivotCCW6.rotation.z >= -0.5*Math.PI)){
            //CW
            centerPivotCW6.add(mesh1);
            centerPivotCW6.add(mesh4);
            centerPivotCW6.add(mesh6);
            centerPivotCW6.add(mesh7);

            mesh1.rotation.x=2*Math.PI;
            mesh4.rotation.x=Math.PI;
            mesh6.rotation.x=2*Math.PI;
            mesh7.rotation.x=Math.PI;

            //CCW
            centerPivotCCW6.add(mesh2);
            centerPivotCCW6.add(mesh3);
            centerPivotCCW6.add(mesh5);
            centerPivotCCW6.add(mesh8);

            mesh2.rotation.x=2*Math.PI;
            mesh3.rotation.x=Math.PI;
            mesh5.rotation.x=2*Math.PI;
            mesh8.rotation.x=Math.PI;

            centerPivotCCW6.rotation.z += -Math.PI / 90;
            centerPivotCW6.rotation.z += Math.PI / 90;

            camera.position.y += -0.448;

        }


        render();
            aniframe = requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            controls.update();
    }
```

First of all, I can't really loop this animation, since every object is wrong oriented by getting them to their initial position (guess I need to rearange them manually).
And secondly, I don't know how I can pause within the animation and resume it...or even loop it backwards.

Any helpful tips how to manage animations in threejs?

Comment: Can you break your animations down by mesh, or is your logic entirely dependent on re-parenting the shapes into those extra containers? In other words, can `mesh1` could have an array of all the animation steps it would take, while `mesh2` would have a similar but different array of animation steps? If this is possible, I have a solution for you. If not, then I'll have to think about it more.

Comment: @TheJim01 as long as you can make some meshes run at the same time, I would be glad to hear your idea :)

Comment: Check your version of `THREE.js`. As of r81+, `Object3D` has an `onBeforeRender` property, to which you can assign a function (see the docs for the parameter list). When the renderer goes to render a renderable object, it calls `onBeforeRender` _first_. This means you could allow each mesh to control its own animations through its `onBeforeRender` method. This might not make things more efficient, but it would certainly clean up your code and you animation loop.

Comment: @TheJim01 Thanks for the advice. I'll check it out